# How to fix "Cannot find reference 'channel' in 'message'"

Tags: python, disnake

When writing message.channel.id, shows an error (Cannot find reference 'channel' in 'message'), searched the entire Internet, similar problem as well as the solution has not found.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if message.channel.id == 1218632975441330266:
        pass
    else:
        chan = bot.get_channel(1203013518408810497)
        embed = disnake.Embed(title=f"{before.author} redacted his message",
        description=f"Before: {before.content}\nAfter: {after.content}\nAuthor:     {before.author.mention}\nWhere: {before.channel.mention}",
        timestamp=datetime.now(), color=disnake.Colour.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=after.author.name, icon_url=after.author.display_avatar)
        await chan.send(embed=embed)
```

I know that I need to add message to the arguments, but after I add it, the "after" argument simply doesn't work, and I get an error TypeError: on_message_edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'after', so I can't even guess how to do it..

Disnake version 2.9.1 (I checked this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_message_edit` is only expecting `before`, and `after` as an argument, you can't just pass another argument in it.
To check for the message channel id, you can use `before.channel.id`, since `before` and `after` are of type [disnake.Message](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/messages.html#disnake.Message):

```py
if before.channel.id == 1218632975441330266:
   return
```